# Regex validation to don't allow submission of numbers which starts with given sequence

Tags: regex, validation

we Have an issue with spammers and I'd like to add a validation regex to the phone field in my form, in order to don't allow input which starts with a particular sequence of numbers.

I am using a wordpress plugin to build up the form, and I can add custom regex validation to each field.
so at the moment for my phone field I am using a text field and I have this regex to allow only numbers: /^\d+$/

the prefixes I'd like to block are these:
+44704, +44714, 0704, 0714, 0044704, 0044714

is it possible to create a regex which will check if the input starts with one of these sequences, and if yes it will block them?

If possible I need it to keep allowing only numbers, in addition of allowing only if it's not starting with one of those sequences.

I hope someone will be able to help me, as I really don't understand regex at all.. :(

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of optional groups, like this:

```
^\+?(?:(?:00)?44|0)7[01]4
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/xZ1aV3)

This regex matches only strings that begins with the patterns you described. To negate it, you could use a negative lookahead with the pattern above:

```
^(?!\+?(?:(?:00)?44|0)7[01]4)
```

`^` matches the beginning of the line

`\+?` matches an optional `+` sign.

`(?:(?:00)?44|0)` matches either of: 0044, or 44, or 0

`7[01]4` matches either 704 or 714.

---

To validate the whole entry string and prevent the matches, then add the bit you already had, with an optional `+` sign:

```
/^(?!\+?((00)?44|0)7[01]4)\+?\d+$/
```

Comment: That sounds like what I need! :) the only thing is that I need to keep allowing 0044 or 44 or +44, as that is the normal UK prefix, it's only when is followed by 704 or 714 that is bad. but I can't match only 704 as if those numbers are at the end, they are not the high-cost numbers which I need to exclude. can you tell me how to achieve this please? thank you very much!

Comment: @Pikkio This works for the things you just mentioned. Using `^(?!\+?(?:(?:00)?44|0)7[01]4)` will allow 0044, 44 or +44. The explanation I gave is a single sequence (only broken down for easier understanding) and each has to be followed by the other. Just try it and let me know how it goes :)

Comment: Hi Jerry! I've tried it and it blocks everything.. also a number like this is blocked: 23568952222

Comment: Hmm, there might be something I don't know about with your program. Could you try `^(?!\+?(?:(?:00)?44|0)7[01]4)\+?\d+$`?

Comment: it still not allow any number with that code as well.. I've also tried inserting only letters but it still blocking it.. you can see the form here: http://www.prepaidfuneralplansuk.co.uk/dev/contact/ but I think it won't be very helpful as all the validation is handled by the plugin and I don't know if you can see it in the page code..

Comment: maybe this will give you an hint about how the plugin handle the insert regex: the field is allowing only numbers if I put this code as validation: /^\d+$/

Comment: @Pikkio I'm not sure what might be wrong. You did use the `/` delimiters around the regex I suggested right? Otherwise, maybe change the non-capture groups into capture groups if it doesn't handle non-capture groups? `/^(?!\+?((00)?44|0)7[01]4)\+?\d+$/`

Comment: Hi Jerry! I didn't wrap it in the slashes, that was the problem! -_- I'm sorry if I wasted your time, but yes, I understand THAT much little of regex.. :( The code works like a charm though! Thank you very much mate!

Comment: @Pikkio Haha, that's okay. And it's awesome you got it to work :) You can click on the checkmark outline to accept the answer :)

Comment: ah, by the way, I've used the last code and seems working perfectly. should I prefer the first version for any reason?

Comment: @Pikkio Their function is basically the same, prevent the certain patterns you mentioned from passing. The first also allows anything else (letters, special characters) but the last doesn't. The first should be faster, and is better if you're sure that the number entered will be 'valid'. The last one could be called safer, but with a minor dropback on speed.

Comment: I'll go for the last one then, it's perfect for what I need! :) Thank you very much again. and I love that website you linked where I can eventually test the edits if I'll need to block other numbers in the future. maybe I'll learn something about regex. :) cheers!